# Implementing This Algorithm with Less line of Code at Perl

Tags: perl

I want to implement this algorithm in Perl.
Let's accept that:

- DNA1 = GACTAGGC
- DNA2 = AGCTAGGA

[image]

First element of DNA1 is G, we will find if there is G at DNA2 and point it with a dot. We continue it till the end so the image shows evey same element intersections as a dot.

The next step is that: connecting points. To point to dots first one should be at left top corner of a small square and the other one at right bottom(I mean lines should have a 135 degree) If stringency is 2, it means that reject the lines which has occured from 2 and less then 2 dots(It means that if stringency was 3, there would be just one line at image).

Last step is that: wordcount. If wordcount is 1(it is one at image) it means that compare elements one by one. If it was 3 it means that compare 3 of them together. You can write a program that wordcount is 1 because it is always 1.

I searched about it and this is what I have:

```
$infile1 = "DNA1.txt";
$infile2 = "DNA2.txt";

$outfile = "plot.txt";
$wordsize=0;
$stringency=0;

open inf, $infile1 or die "STOP! File $infile1 not found.\n";
$sequence1=<inf>;
chomp $sequence1;
@seq1=split //,$sequence1;
close inf;

open inf, $infile2 or die "STOP! File $infile2 not found.\n";
$sequence2=<inf>;
chomp $sequence2;
@seq2=split //,$sequence2;
close inf;

$Lseq1=$#seq1+1;
$Lseq2=$#seq2+1;

open ouf, ">$outfile";

for ($i=0;$i<$Lseq1;$i++){
print ouf "\n";
for ($j=0;$j<$Lseq2;$j++){
  $match=0;
  for ($w=0;$w<=$wordsize;$w++){
    if($seq1[$i+$w] eq $seq2[$j+$w]){
      $match++;
    }
  }
  if($match > $stringency){
     print ouf "1";
  }
  else{
     print ouf "0";
  }
}
}
```

Can you check it about errors and how can I optimize my code with more less code at Perl?

**PS:** I think it is OK to accept $wordsize equals to $stringency every time.

**EDIT 1:** I have edited my code and it works for just puting dot.

**EDIT 2:** Algorithm is like that:

```
qseq, sseq = sequences
win = number of elements to compare for each point
Strig = number of matches required for a point

for each q in qseq:
  for each s in sseq:
    if CompareWindow(qseq[q:q+win], s[s:s+win], strig):
      AddDot(q, s)
```

**EDIT 3:** Here is a better algorithm suggestion:

[osl.iu.edu/~chemuell/projects/bioinf/dotplot.ppt](http://osl.iu.edu/~chemuell/projects/bioinf/dotplot.ppt)

Any idea to improve code according to that better algorithm is welcome.

Comment: Why less code, this is pretty short already. In fact, I'd add some code if I were you, at least if you count spaces as code.

Comment: I want to optimize it if I can for example at file operations or changing to loops into any other loops if there is also I am not sure about the code works too.

Comment: One more, this is my third topic about Perl questions and at all of them the comments was like sugestions are quite short and well but at the and I got all the answers just one-line. So that's why I want to optimize it more and more, because it is Perl and I want to learn if it is possible to do something more.

Comment: Here's some more code you should add: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Shorter code doesn't run faster. It's just an excuse for the author to show off his ability to write obfuscated, difficult to maintain code. That kind of thing can be fun for sig files & Perl golf, but it has no place in scripts that are used for real work.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley That's what I want to do exactly. I want to correct and optimize and write less line of code if possible for fun.

Comment: @kamaci: While I had fun bumming your other examples down to short lines, the fun was also based on (mis)using Perl primitives to do the work in as few steps as possible. But as @Sherm Pendley notes, short code is rarely the most efficient; DNA sequences are typically hundreds of thousands base pairs long, and I would think the fun part would be in bumming cycles from the inner loop instead. That said, I do have some nasty idea using XOR on strings and `tr///` -- too bad Perl doesn't have a bytewise shift operator -- but this comment field is too small to contain them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the innermost for loop is totally unnecessary. Getting rid of it will speed up your code.

Secondly, your code doesn't work for $stringency other than 0.

Fix:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s1 = 'GACTAGGC';
my $s2 = 'AGCTAGGA';
my $stringency = 0;

my @s1 = split //, $s1;
my @s2 = split //, $s2;
my @L;
for my $i (0..$#s1) {
   for my $j (0..$#s2) {
      if ($s1[$i] ne $s2[$j]) {
         $L[$i][$j] = 0;
      } elsif ($i == 0 || $j == 0) {
         $L[$i][$j] = 1;
      } else {
         $L[$i][$j] = $L[$i-1][$j-1] + 1;
      }

      print $L[$i][$j] <= $stringency ? "0" : "1";
   }
   print("\n");
}
```

Now that we have an efficient algorithm, we can tweak the implementation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s1 = 'GACTAGGC';
my $s2 = 'AGCTAGGA';
my $stringency = 0;

my @s1 = split //, $s1;
my @s2 = split //, $s2;
my @L = (0) x @s2;
for my $i (0..$#s1) {
   for my $j (0..$#s2) {
      if ($s1[$i] eq $s2[$j]) {
         ++$L[$j];
      } else {
         $L[$j] = 0;
      }

      print $L[$j] <= $stringency ? "0" : "1";
   }

   print("\n");
   pop @L;
   unshift @L, 0;
}
```

If you want a better idea of what's going on, replace

```
print $L[$j] <= $stringency ? "0" : "1";
```

with

```
print $L[$j];
```

You'll get something like

```
01000110
10001002
00100000
00020000
10003001
02000410
01000150
00200000
```

By the way, what are trying to achieve is remarkably similar to finding the [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

**Update** To get `$s1` and `$s2` from files, one line at a time,

```
open(my $fh1, '<', ...) or die(...);
open(my $fh2, '<', ...) or die(...);

for (;;) {
    my $s1 = <$fh1>;
    my $s2 = <$fh2>;

    die("Files have different length\n")
        if defined($s1) && !defined($s2)
        || !defined($s1) && defined($s2);

    last if !defined(($s1);

    chomp($s1);
    chomp($s2);

    ... code to generate graph ...
}
```

Comment: Can you read them from file and split them while reading them at one-line?

Comment: @kamaci, Of course you can read a file a line at a time. I didn't include in in my script because it's noise as far as the question is concerned. If you need help with reading from a file, I suggest you create another question.

Comment: I changed reading from file part but your code works well, thanks.